# What's the best food?

Tags: the-sims-2

The Sims 2 has an involved cuisine system wherein ingredients (up to a max of 4) can be combined and cooked in different ways. Ingredients differ in how well they affect the Hunger motive, Bladder, Energy, and Fun. Some combinations even have special (albethem temporary) effects such as aphrodisiac (pink hearts), black hearts (forces angry socialization), poisonous (emetic or even lethal), and skill-boosting (stars, boosts all skills by three).

Which recipe(s) is/are the most useful?

I think it's rather important to denote that this is The Sims 2 (TS2) for consoles (in particular, the Nintendo GameCube), because I think The Sims 2 is rather different between console and PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Llama + Ostrich + Orange + Strawberry = perfect (skills-booster), aphrodisiac."

Although this is only available later, once the U-Probe-It Refrigerating Organism (top-tier refrigerator) has been unlocked by acquiring enough Aspiration points, it is crazy useful. As the quote from my journal says, it's a skill-booster ("perfect" being a descriptor for a skill-boosting food) AND an aphrodisiac. Perfect for slipping a ro-I mean, offering as a gift to the NPC that you wish to charm to make social interactions go swimmingly.

On top of that, I found this by combining the ingredients with the highest energy stat, ignoring ingredients that must be harvested. That means two things:

(1) You'll fill about half of your energy bar with one bite of this recipe. If you've cooked it into a dish rather than a drink, you can cancel eating it, then eat it again to apply the effect twice and fully refill your energy with one meal. Or else, prepare it as a drink (smoothie) to earn its benefits at the speed of one gulp. This stuff is better than [brand-name energy drink].

(2) You don't need to harvest anything to make this recipe. You can get these ingredients as long as you have the fridge and the simoleans.

But, until you can unlock the U-Probe-It Refrigerating Organism, espressos are great, just like in The Sims (1) for consoles. Three cups will fully refill your Energy motive meter, but be sure to place it near a toilet, because it'll affect your Bladder a lot. I've placed the espresso machine on a one-tile table next to the garbage can out front so that the leftover cup can just be thrown away, since it generates a lot of rubbish.

Either way, sleep should become a throwback.